# Install Tesseract for AWS linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, installation, ocr, tesseract

How to install Tesseract in AWS Linux? One of our team member tried the below commands a few months ago.

```
cd /opt
mkdir tesseract
chmod 0755 tesseract
cd tesseract

yum install libpng-devel
yum install libtiff-devel
yum install libjpeg-devel
wget http://www.leptonica.com/source/leptonica-1.71.tar.gz 
tar xzf leptonica-1.71.tar.gz
cd leptonica-1.71
./configure
make
make install
export LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include # Add to .profile

cd /opt/tesseract
yum install libtool
wget https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
tar xzf tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz # Makes tesseract-ocr directory, no version.
cd tesseract-ocr
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-extra-libraries=/opt/tesseract
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig

cd /opt/tesseract
wget https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz
tar xzf tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz # Makes tesseract-ocr/tessdata directory.
sudo cp ./tessdata/* /usr/local/share/tessdata/ | for each
$>rm –rf tessdata 
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/tesseract/tesseract-ocr/
```

But these commands didn't helped. When we are ran [Tesseract OCR for PHP](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php), we got the below error.

> Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. Make sure you have Tesseract OCR installed on your system

It will be helpful if someone shares any tutorial/documentation links.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you please check and help?

Comment: I have no knowledge of tesseract, but that error is saying that the command you ran is not found. It is probably installed in some directory (eg `/usr/local/share/tessdata/`), so try running your command from there.

Comment: `tesseract` is in the EPEL repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL ... for el6, el7, el8 .

Answer (score 19):

This should work on Amazon Linux 2:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install tesseract
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan

I followed your steps in the third command I get this error:

```
Error: Package: leptonica-1.72-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: leptonica-1.72-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is old but still it saved me and hence sharing it for the future

```
yum install -y git libtool clang gcc-c++.x86_64
yum install -y zlib zlib-devel libjpeg libjpeg-devel libwebp libwebp-devel libtiff libtiff-devel libpng libpng-devel

cp /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/local/lib/
cp /usr/lib64/libwebp.so.4 /usr/local/lib/
cp /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5 /usr/local/lib/
cp /usr/lib64/libpng15.so.15 /usr/local/lib/

rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y update
yum install -y tesseract
```