Installing teserract in AWS Beanstalk
I was deploying a flask application that has a dependency with Tesseract library and I am getting below error.
No match for argument: 
Error: Unable to find a match: tesseract

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

I tried below commands
yum install -y tesseract
I also tried to download rpm files and tried local installing it. But nothing worked
and I also tried pip installing. How to resolve it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208140/install-tesseract-for-aws-linux
Check this answer

I tried that one. It's not working.

are you using amazon linux 2023 or amazon linux 2? According to this link https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/534 al2023 doesn't have tesseract yet.  Either you switch to amazon-linux 2 or find a way to tweak al2023 like the answer above
